# Logut with SignInManager not calling method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor, .net-core

After login to SomePage.cshtml I want to make **Logout** button. The method to logout is inside different controller.

Here is my method which I'm using:

**AccountController.cs**

```
...
 private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> sim;
...
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await sim.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("/Account/Login");            
}
```

But I got problem to run this *Logout*. This is my **method** which I'm trying to run from **SomePage.cshtml**:

```
<div>
...
 <form method="post" action="Account/Logout">
   <button type="submit">Logout</button>
 </form>
...
</div>
```

When I click Logout it try to redirect under **/Account/Logout**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the method decorator to use `[HttpPost]`. You have set form action to `post` in your form action, so that will not hit your current endpoint as it's only receives `GET`. You will also need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside your form so that it is supplied in your request. See below code...

**AccountController.cs**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await sim.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("/Login");            
}
```

**SomePage.cshtml**

```
 <form method="post" action="/Account/Logout">
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <button type="submit">Logout</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: can you please put correct code for *cshtml* ? I have already changed controller method to [HttpPost]

Comment: Try this

<form method="post" action="Account/Logout">
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <button type="submit">Logout</button>
 </form>

Comment: I got this:
**No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:62995/SomePage/Account/Logout**

Comment: Change the action to "/Account/Logout"

Comment: please put your answer as **code** then I will accept it , I also did one change: **RedirectToAction("Login")**

Comment: @4est Great news, glad you managed to get it resolved. I've updated my answer to include the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the request: `form method="post"`, but the controller method is decorated with the `[HttpGet]` attribute, and thereby accepts GET requests.

Comment: I change it and now it's **Account/Logout?**....also I removed *action="Account/Logout"* but still method button is not run my Logout method

Comment: If you check the developer window of your browser, what request is sent then?

Comment: SomePage.cshtml, status 200

Comment: That is the response, what is the request that is sent from your browser?

Comment: You are not telling the browser where to send the request, put the action="Account/Logout" back.

Comment: ok, now it's **Status Code: 400 Bad Request**, and **Account/Logout?**